# C# - Regular Expression not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have written the following Regular Expression.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString =@"(\<\![a-b]+\!\>)+") ]
```

It is to match the string

```
<!abc!>
```

The whole string is required.

But this  particular expression matches  up even with `<` only.
 and `<!` too.

Can someone pls correct it if I have done it wrong ?

Comment: What is ur expected output

Comment: You obviously don't want to match the same string everywhere! If that's the case then it drafts the purpose of using Regex

Comment: I tried [your regex at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5c%3c%5c!%5ba-b%5d%2b%5c!%5c%3e)%2b&i=%3c), and  it just misses `c`. It does not match just `<` or `<!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping things that you should not, and you did not include `c` in your range.  Here is a correct RegEx:

```
<![a-c]+!>
```

Tip: Check out http://regexr.com/  It is a great (free) online tool for testing, and learning about, RegEx's.

Comment: Thank you ! especially, for the link :)

Comment: I'd rather suggest regexhero.net or regexstorm.net that support .NET regex syntax. Also, what is the purpose of the `+` quantifier at the end? It allows matching `<!abcabc!>>>>>>>>>>>` - is it expected behavior?

Comment: @stribizhev: `Also, what is the purpose of the + quantifier at the end?`  No cut/paste error from regexr.com.  Updated.  Thanks for the other sites.  I only tend to use simple RegEx, so regexr.com has worked fine for me.  I'll check out the ones you suggest.